# How to send data from one pipeline to another in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Hello I have two pipelines, the first one to download photos:

```
class ModelsPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        image_url_hash = hashlib.shake_256(request.url.encode()).hexdigest(5)
        image_filename = f'{item["name"]}/{image_url_hash}.jpg'

        return image_filename

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]

        for image in image_paths:
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)[1]
            img_path = f'{IMAGES_STORE}{image}'
            md5 = hashlib.md5(open(img_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
            img_destination = f'{IMAGES_STORE}{item["name"]}/{md5}{file_extension}'
            os.rename(img_path, img_destination)

        return item
```

The second one is to store previous info in the database

```
class DatabasePipeline():

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = db_connect()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.client.upsert(item)
```

The item_completed function in the first pipeline, returns a name and a path that I want to send to the second pipeline in order to store in the database, but I can not get access to that data.

The question is how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the name and the path to the item in the ModelsPipeline:

```
item['name_from_pipeline'] = name
item['path_from_pipeline'] = path
return item
```

In process_item of the DatabasePipeline you can access it:

```
name = item['name_from_pipeline']
path = item['path_from_pipeline']
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem recently.
You need to enable both pipelines and assign a lower priority to the DatabasePipeline like the following. Higher number means lower priority
.

So the data will be processed first by ModelsPipeline then by DatabasePipeline.
Remember to return the item inside the process of ModelsPipeline

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   "project_name.pipelines.ModelsPipeline": 300, 
   "project_name.pipelines.DatabasePipeline": 302,
}
```